# How can i deserialize Json string where object's field's subclass is included in json string, using Java and Jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am very new to Java. I have some classes Site, Instances, CloudInstance. Class Site has an attribute instances and class CloudInstance inherits class Instance. They are as follows-

```
  public class Site extends BaseEntity {
      private String siteName;
      List<Instance> instances = Lists.newArrayList();
  }

  public class Instance extends BaseEntity {
    private String instanceId;
    private String name;
  }

  public class CloudInstance extends Instance {
    private String availabilityZone;
    private String instanceType
  }
```

I am deserializing json string as follows -

```
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
  BaseEntity obj = null;
  obj = (BaseEntity) mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Site.class);
```

It works fine if my jsonStr does not contain fields of class 'CloudInstance' and contains field instance with Instance class's fields.

Problem - Now i want to deserialize the jsonStr which includes 'CloudInstance' classe's fiels as well as the part of 'instances' field of class 'Site'. Ex jsonStr is as follows -

```
  {
        "id": null,
        "siteName": "demo",
        "instances": [
            {
                "instanceId": "i-8c2ee5fc",
                "name": "some-node",
                "availabilityZone": "some-zone",
                "instanceType": "t1.micro"  
            }]
   }
```

For the above jsonStr i get following error

```
  error: Unrecognized field \"availabilityZone\" and error: Unrecognized field \"instanceType\"
```

With lots of if else and dirty code i can get the obj of Site including above fields. But i want to implement clean solution for this.
Is there any library which can do this? Any help id valuable. Please help..!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called polymorphic deserialization. Your example fails because Jackson needs to know what instance type should be constructed from JSON and placed to the list of instances. Please refer to [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) wiki page for detailed explanation.

I have modified you example to demonstrate how it could work. I've added the instance type information in the `@type` field in the JSON representation. Also I've made all the classes immutable using constructors annotated with [the @JsonCreator annotation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureCreators) to create instances.

```
public class JacksonPolymorphism {

    public static class BaseEntity {
        private final String id;

        protected BaseEntity(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    public static class Site extends BaseEntity {
        private final String siteName;
        private final List<Instance> instances;

        @JsonCreator
        public Site(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                    @JsonProperty("siteName") String siteName,
                    @JsonProperty("instances") List<Instance> instances) {
            super(id);
            this.siteName = siteName;
            this.instances = instances;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Site{" +
                    "siteName='" + siteName + '\'' +
                    ", instances=" + instances +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
            property = "@type")
    @JsonTypeName(value = "simple")
    public static class Instance extends BaseEntity {
        private final String name;

        @JsonCreator
        public Instance(@JsonProperty("instanceId") String id,
                        @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
            super(id);
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Instance{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeName("cloud")
    public static class CloudInstance extends Instance {
        private final String availabilityZone;
        private final String instanceType;


        public CloudInstance(@JsonProperty("instanceId") String id,
                             @JsonProperty("name") String name,
                             @JsonProperty("availabilityZone") String availabilityZone,
                             @JsonProperty("instanceType") String instanceType) {
            super(id, name);
            this.availabilityZone = availabilityZone;
            this.instanceType = instanceType;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CloudInstance{" +
                    "availabilityZone='" + availabilityZone + '\'' +
                    ", instanceType='" + instanceType + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static final String JSON = "{\n" +
            "        \"id\": null,\n" +
            "        \"siteName\": \"demo\",\n" +
            "        \"instances\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"@type\": \"cloud\",\n" +
            "                \"instanceId\": \"i-8c2ee5fc\",\n" +
            "                \"name\": \"some-node\",\n" +
            "                \"availabilityZone\": \"some-zone\",\n" +
            "                \"instanceType\": \"t1.micro\"  \n" +
            "            }," +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"@type\": \"simple\",\n" +
            "                \"instanceId\": \"ABC\",\n" +
            "                \"name\": \"FGF\"\n" +
            "            }]" +
            "   }";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerSubtypes(CloudInstance.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, Site.class));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Site{siteName='demo', instances=[CloudInstance{availabilityZone='some-zone', instanceType='t1.micro'}, Instance{name='FGF'}]}
```

Comment: Thx Alexey  Problem is solved. I have a same problem with 2 more classes let say class "A" and class "B" where "B" extends "A". But "A" doesnt defines "B" as an attribute/field (A has no reference to B) .And "A" and "B" are in different module. When i try to deserialize the json string i get error Unrecognized field. my ques is how to provide annotation for them 
@XmlRootElement
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type",defaultImpl=A.class)
@JsonTypeName(value = "a")
For "B"
@JsonTypeName(value = "b") 
this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I always had problems to deserialize JSON that contains List<...> objects with Jackson, so try to deserialize with Gson:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Take a look at the documentation in the methods fromJson and toJson.

I hope that can help,
Best regards

Comment: Is there a way in gson to map string to object. In the context of above ex whic can map abive json string (containing CloudInstances attributes) to Site object ?

Answer (score 0):

Never had consistent luck with Jackson or Gson, try [Flex JSON](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.flexjson/flexjson/2.0) instead:

```
 JSONSerializer ser = new JSONSerializer();
 String json = ser.deepSerialize(yourObject);
 JSONDeserializer<YourMainType> der = new JSONDeserializer<YourMainType>();
 YourMainType mainType = der.deserialize(json);
```

For this to work, all classes subject to serialization/deserialization must expose getters/setters consistent with Java Beans convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can used [GSON Library](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for de-serialize your Json into your class object.

There is function `gson.fromJson(JSON String)` which convert json string to class object.

Here is Sample code :

```
Gson json = new Gson();
Site site = json.fromJson(jsonStr, Site.class);
```

But in your code you have replace

```
List<Instance> instances = Lists.newArrayList();
```

this line in class `Site` with

```
 List<CloudInstance> instances = new ArrayList<CloudInstance>();
```

Because your `CloudInstance` class extend  `Instance` it means `CloudInstance` class include member of `Instance` class. As per json you need to do this to cast directly into class object.

May this will help you.

Comment: This is not posible because Site is designed to have instances as well as cloudInstances. Class implementation can not be changed. Please suggest any other way.

Comment: I dont think any other way for this , because `CloudInstance` member variable is not present on `Instance` class. How could you include member which is not present in that class while deserialization?

Comment: Yes its a big challenge to complete.Yes CloudInstance member variable is not present on Instance class but CloudInstance inherits Instance.